# Remote Desktop installation in Event Viewer - not triggered by me

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, event-viewer

This issue is for Windows 10 operating in a home environment.

I was looking in Event Viewer for another reason and have found a recurring message that is concerning to me:

Windows Logs -> Application ->

```
Error MsiInstaller Event ID 11925

Product: Remote Desktop -- Error 1925. You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine.  Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.
```

The running user is my local user on the machine (this is a personal PC, not operating under domain controls). The process appears to run every time I log on to my PC.

There's an info message before it that shows the executable being run:

```
Beginning a Windows Installer transaction: C:\Users\[MyUsername]\AppData\Local\Temp\RemoteDesktop.msi. Client Process Id: 13180.
Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Remote Desktop. Product Version: 1.2.3004.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

I don't really know how or why this process is occurring so I'm a bit concerned. I understand it would be common for such a process to happen in an enterprise domain. Unfortunately all information I've found via searching is from enterprise IT people who are trying to do this on purpose - I can't find any explanation of why this would happen on a local personal account.

Is this a virus attempting to create access? Is this a standard Windows process? Something I can disable?

I'd appreciate some guidance to figure out what is going on.

Comment: "Is this a virus attempting to create access?" - No; How do I know? The process was attempting to be run out of the user's own temporary AppData directory.  That isn't the typical behavior of a malicious process.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, it helped me focus a bit more on what could be causing it from a non-malicious perspective and I found the solution with a bit more debugging.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this exact error and event was caused by the "new Remote Desktop client" (MSRDC) for Windows not being able to update itself - Here is the official link to the app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windowsdesktop#install-the-client

Bare in mind it is also available as a Microsoft Store app, in my case I had installed it from the above link. As usual, they may look identical but are technically different apps.

In my case I hadn't used in a week or so and by chance I noticed these 11925 application errors while routinely checking the logs yesterday. Checked the usual RDP(MSTSC) client - worked fine so was confused and started thinking about viruses/malware etc...

Good thing I tried starting the new RDP app and immediately got the update notification. Allowed it and eventvwr confirmed it got installed fine this time!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out why this was occurring by following a few steps.

**Enable all task history in task scheduler**
In the Windows Task Scheduler I had previously looked in the history and scheduled tasks and couldn't find anything related. In the Actions window I enabled 'All task history' and waited for the process to run again.

**Review task scheduler history**
A few hours later the mystery process ran again and I was able to see the following task in the task history:

```
Remote Desktop Feed Refresh Task
```

I'm pretty sure it wasn't listed previously (I don't know how I could miss it) but there's also a folder for `Remote Desktop -> [Username]` in the task scheduler library. It lists a process that executes `C:\Program Files\Remote Desktop\msrdcw.exe /refresh` every 4 hours. This process was created the RemoteDesktop.msi installer in temp and attempting to install it to update.

I'm guessing some security control in Windows prevents the scheduled tasks from installing RemoteDesktop and so the process fails and loops every 4 hours.